# Set an empty DateTime variable

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I would declare an empty String variable like this:

```
    string myString = string.Empty;
```

Is there an equivalent for a 'DateTime' variable ?

Update :

The problem is I use this 'DateTime' as a parameter for a 'StoredProcedure' in SQL.
E.g:

```
    DateTime? someDate = null;
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurgeryDate", someDate);
```

When I run this code an exception is catched telling me the 'StoredProcedure' expected a '@SurgeryDate' parameter.
But i provided it.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Since `DateTime` is a value type you cannot assign `null` to it, but exactly for these cases (absence of a value) [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) was introduced - use a nullable `DateTime` instead:

```
DateTime? myTime = null;
```

Comment: Will this 'Nullable' DateTime fit in a SQL Database column of type DateTime ?
I'm new to this.

Comment: Yes - if the column allows inserting null values

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Most databases will have a setting for whether or not the value is can be set to null.

Comment: As I said before, you should check your database schema.  Whether a column can be null or not is a setting; you need to check if it's set or not and set it if it's not.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: You'd have to check for `null` and insert `DBNull.Value` in this case, otherwise `myTime.Value`

Answer (score 42):

No. You have 2 options:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
```

This works when you need to do something every X amount of time (since you will always be over `MinValue`) but can actually cause subtle errors (such as using some operators w/o first checking if you are not `MinValue`) if you are not careful.

And you can use `Nullable`:

```
DateTime? date = null;
```

Which is nice and avoids most issues while introducing only 1 or 2.

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 16):

You can set a DateTime variable to be '1/1/0001 00:00:00' but the variable itself cannot be null. To get this MinTime use:

```
DateTime variableName = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use a nullable datetime.  `Datetime? someDate = null;`

You may find instances of people using `DateTime.Max` or `DateTime.Min` in such instances, but I highly doubt you want to do that.  It leads to bugs with edge cases, code that's harder to read, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Either:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
```

or

```
DateTime dt = default(DateTime);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you set the date to

```
DateTime someDate = new DateTime();
```

> The value of 'someDate' is set to {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}

Answer (score 5):

The method you used (`AddWithValue`) doesn't convert `null` values to database nulls. You should use [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@SurgeryDate", 
    someDate == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)someDate
);
```

This will pass the `someDate` value if it is not `null`, or `DBNull.Value` otherwise. In this case correct value will be passed to the database.

Comment: ok I like this approach but could you please explain the last line..?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: this is for more general scenario - your have a variable `someDate` of type `Nullable<DateTime>`. If its value is `null` I pass `DBNull.Value` to the `AddWithValue` method. Otherwise I pass the value itself.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know we could do that!

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Use a nullable DateTime?

Option 2: Use DateTime.MinValue

Personally, I'd prefer option 1.

Answer (score 3):

A `string` is a *sequence* of characters. So it makes sense to have an empty `string`, which is just an empty sequence of characters.

But `DateTime` is just a single value, so it's doesn't make sense to talk about an “empty” `DateTime`.

If you want to represent the concept of “no value”, that's represented as `null` in .Net. And if you want to use that with value types, you need to explicitly make them nullable. That means either using `Nullable<DateTime>`, or the equivalent `DateTime?`.

`DateTime` (just like all value types) also has a *default value*, that's assigned to uninitialized fields and you can also get it by `new DateTime()` or `default(DateTime)`. But you probably don't want to use it, since it represents valid date: 1.1.0001 0:00:00.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as an empty date per se, do you mean something like:

```
DateTime? myDateTime = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The .addwithvalue needs dbnull.
You could do something like this:

```
DateTime? someDate = null;
//...
if (someDate == null)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurgeryDate", DBnull.value);
```

or use a method extension...

```
  public static class Extensions
    {
        public static SqlParameter AddWithNullValue(this SqlParameterCollection collection, string parameterName, object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, DBNull.Value);
            else
                return collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for null able dateTime parameter

. .

```
SearchUsingDate(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate){
     DateTime LastDate;
     if (EndDate != null)
       {
          LastDate = (DateTime)EndDate;
          LastDate = LastDate.AddDays(1);
          EndDate = LastDate;
        }
}
```