# deserialize a object to return empty string for object type nullable datetime

Tags: c#, linq, deserialization, jsonconvert

I am trying to deserialize a object. It returns null for a object of nullable datetime (Collected)

```
public async var GetOrders()
{
    var orders =  await db
            .GetDataTableAsync($"query")
            .GetRows()
            .Select(r => new
            {
                OrderContent = (dynamic) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r["json"].ToString())
            }).ToList();

    return orders;
}

public class OrderInfo
{
    public DateTime? Collected { get; set; } 

    public string TypeID { get; set; }
}
```

result:

```json
{
    "Collected": null,
    "TypeID": 1
}
```

expected:

```json
{
    "Collected": "",
    "TypeID": 1
}
```

Comment: `DateTime?` is either `null` or some type of `DateTime`, `""` is a `string`.

Comment: Your question and code talk about *deserialization*, but your "expected result" could only be the result of *serialization*. It's not quite clear what you're expecting here.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am deserializing objects returned by query, when deserialized it returns null, I want it to return a emptystring

Comment: @RyanWilson yes! but is there a way to convert it empty string ""?

Comment: You need to show the JSON you are deserializing.

Comment: @prathapshetty Sure you can convert to empty string, but you can't set a `DateTime?` to an empty string. Your model is currently expecting a `Nullable<DateTime>` for that property. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982839/set-an-empty-datetime-variable)

Comment: @RyanWilson thank you. I was able to use contract resolvers and get it done

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom json serializer. Pls. see two articles:

1. [Json Convert empty string instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830206/json-convert-empty-string-instead-of-null)
2. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179047/customizing-response-serialization-in-asp-net-core-mvc/49189185)